# q-img calling computed function not showing image Quasar

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, src, quasar

Here's my struggle, i'm trying to display an image from my db, i correctly grab the path of the image from my db, but when i try to put this path in the :src="", src="",or whatever img src it's not showing.

in the inspector i found that when using :src, my getHeader[0].path is taken as a module,

and when using simply src, inspector said that image is not found, because it's tryin to GET on my api, but i just want to put a path of the image in the local ~assets folder.

thanks for replying

`<q-img :src="getHeader[0].path" />`

```
 computed: {
    ...mapGetters("header", ["flashGetter"]),
   
    ...mapGetters("header", ["getHeader"]),
```